# Beijing customs asking me to wait until 2020 to show receipts, is this normal?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china

I travelled to China last week to see family and was stopped by customs and they removed several items which I had brought for gifts and told me I need to show the receipts to pay tax.

I’m ok with that, but and this is the whole point of this post. The next day I called them to arrange to go and show them and pay my duty and collect my things.

They told me I need to wait till March 2020. Surely this is wrong on so many levels.

Please can someone give me any advice?

Comment: Why wasn't it possible to pay duty directly?

Comment: They wanted the receipts for the goods to work out the tax

Comment: Can I ask what goods we're talking about here?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold for now.